# How to get all child node values as a array while parent node is selected in jstree checkbox plugin

Tags: jstree

I am working on jstree checkbox plugin and want to get all child node values while parent node is selected.I tried to implement get_checked method but it didn't work.

Below is my code.

```
<div id="demo"></div>

$('#demo').jstree({
'core' : {
    'data' : [
        { "text" : "adya", "children" : [
            { "text" : "id" },
            { "text" : "name"},
            {"text":"address"}
        ]
        },
        { "text" : "order", "children" : [
            { "text" : "id" },
            { "text" : "order_name" }
        ]}
    ]
},
'checkbox':{'two_state':true,'whole_node':false,'tie_selection':false},
'plugins':['checkbox','themes','ui'] });
a = [];
$('#demo').jstree("get_checked",null,true).each(function() 
 { a.push(this.id) });
console.log(a);
```

Please help me out.

Comment: Were you able to find the fix at last?

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
jQuery.jstree._reference("#demo")._get_children(parentNode);
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want to select all the children nodes of a selected parent node.
for this you can use `get_children_dom(obj)` method ([see docs here](https://www.jstree.com/api/#/?f=get_children_dom(obj))), here the argument '`obj`' is parent's full node object. To get all the selected parent node objects, you can use `get_top_selected()` method. then for each parent node, you can get their child nodes.

In your code you can do

```
   var parentNodes = $('#demo').jstree().get_top_selected(true);
   var selectedChildNodes;
     $.each(parentNodes, function(index,value){
        selectedChildNodes = $('#demo').jstree().get_children_dom(value);
     });
```